# ExtUtils::MakeMaker conditional/prompt for live tests

Tags: perl

I can't figure out how to get [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.92/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm) to prompt the user asking if the want to run a subset of the tests in `/t` which require live internet connection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you do not want to run such tests on end-user's system. You can not rely on it being reliable, even if it's present. But if you really want to do this you can use the [prompt](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#prompt) helper function together with the [test](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#test) section argument to achieve this if you put the networking tests in its own directory:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

…

my $network = prompt("Do you want to run tests requiring network access [y/n]", "n") =~ /y/i;

WriteMakefile(
    ...
    test => {
        TESTS => $network ? 't/*.t t/network/*.t' : 't/*.t'
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach I remember seeing in the wild is to SKIP those tests by default but print information telling the user to set a certain environment variable if the test should be executed.

Since test are just perl code you can ask the user there and skip accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/ say /;
use Term::ReadKey;
use Test::More;

say "Do you want to run tests with live internet connectivity? [y/n]";

my $key = <>;

ok(1, 'first test');

SKIP: {
    skip('you said you dont want to run these', 1) if $key ne 'y';
    ok(1, 'second test, skippable');
}

ok(1, 'third test');

done_testing;
```

Comment: No, this is just wrong and dangerous. This will hang on a smoker, or in fact any tester that doesn't have a user connected directly to the tests (so that's even cpanm unless in verbose mode).

Comment: I can see that for the code example I posted, not for the environment variable approach though.